# Reverse engineering CRC

Tags: reverse-engineering, crc, crc16

I have data approximately 750 bytes long, which is protected by CRC. I want to make changes to the data but not knowing the CRC scheme means I cannot do it. But I have the luxury of observing the CRC value for sample data. I used this really cool mathematical technique described [here](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/essays/CRC-Reverse-Engineering.html)

I identified CRC as the last two bytes of the data block because, when I change only 1 bit of the data and XOR it, the result is all zeros except that bit and the last two bytes.

I was able to generate C1, C2 for difference messages like this:

```
byte 222 = 0x01; CRC = 0x6D10
byte 222 = 0x02; CRC = 0xEA6D
byte 222 = 0x04; CRC = 0xA494
byte 222 = 0x08; CRC = 0x3966
```

Since the messages are "difference messages" as described in the above link, we can safely ignore XorIn and XorOut values of the CRC. But the reflectIn and ReflectOut parameters can still affect the process. For all the four combinations, I checked to see if (C2<<1) XOR C1 is zero when the MSB of C2 is zero. But this is not the case. I wonder where I went wrong.

Comment: Why not just make the desired change, and generate a fresh CRC?  It's not clear how you can get CRC for sample data, but not for your modified data.

Comment: I will not have access to the software that generates CRC in the future. So I need to figure out how to do it.

Comment: How fast do you need to find the correct CRC after your change?  And how do you test if the CRC in the last two bytes is considered correct?

Comment: Also, the hyperlink does not appear to work, at least not on my machine.

Comment: The hyperlink works now. It is not possible to do trial and error CRC calculation because to see whether it is the right one or wrong one takes a long time. The reason is I write the data to an embedded system, which performs the CRC check.

Comment: Use [RevEng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/). It will solve for the CRC parameters with sufficient examples.